# Implement DES in C#

Tags: c#, des

In the Microsoft page they have a tutorial how to use DES using the built in library:

```
private static void EncryptData(String inName, String outName, byte[] desKey, byte[] desIV)
{
    //Create the file streams to handle the input and output files.
    FileStream fin = new FileStream(inName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    FileStream fout = new FileStream(outName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    fout.SetLength(0);

    //Create variables to help with read and write. 
    byte[] bin = new byte[100]; //This is intermediate storage for the encryption. 
    long rdlen = 0;              //This is the total number of bytes written. 
    long totlen = fin.Length;    //This is the total length of the input file. 
    int len;                     //This is the number of bytes to be written at a time.

    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(fout, des.CreateEncryptor(desKey, desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    Console.WriteLine("Encrypting...");

    //Read from the input file, then encrypt and write to the output file. 
    while (rdlen < totlen)
    {
        len = fin.Read(bin, 0, 100);
        encStream.Write(bin, 0, len);
        rdlen = rdlen + len;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes processed", rdlen);
    }

    encStream.Close();
    fout.Close();
    fin.Close();
}
```

Well I got the most of it, but i didn't understand what is desIV and how can I call the function to test it.. 
Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you researched initialization vectors? Thats what an IV is in this context.

Comment: Yea but still I didn't understand it totally ...

Comment: I need some example to simplify it
Can you please help?

Comment: Honestly; this answer explains it way better than I could: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/732/why-use-an-initialization-vector-iv

Comment: your title suggests you are implementing DES _yourself_, when you're actually confused about what a certain variable in a code example is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might not be a very technical explanation, but I guess a very good way to understand that is thinking about passwords.

Imagine that an attacker could download your whole database of logins and could retrieve everyone's passwords along with their e-mail accounts. But before that, he decides to create some accounts (with some passwords he knows).

If the encryption used just a key, maybe someone could try to 'decode' your key just by having some sample pairs of unencrypted passwords and encrypted ones (using the accounts he created before) and then use the key + the algorithm to decipher every password in the whole database. A worse scenario would be several users with the same password having the same resulted encryption - the attacker wouldn't need even to decipher the key to use other accounts. He would only have to be a good "known passwords" guesser.

Now let's suppose you could introduce some 'ramdom' code at the begging of your encryption/decryption. I.E.: when a user chooses password '12345' instead of encrypting this, you encrypt his e-mail also concatenated 'test@gmail.test12345' and then encrypt. Since there's no way to have two different login e-mails, even if a lot of users choose to use the same password, the resulted encryption would be different. Plus, an attacker would never know what kind of pseudorandom information you have input. This is called 'Salting'.

Salting is not very different than initialization vector, but uses different conventions - this one is array of bytes, but it would mean a string. Some engineers even generate random strings as salt and stores it along the encrypted password. As unrepeatable the the salt is, as difficult to decrypt.

Comment: You should use "hash" instead of "encrypt" in a password database anyways. If a hacker has access to your database, they most certainly have access to your code to encrypt/decrypt passwords.

Comment: @ColeJohnson you are right. Passwords must be encrypted with one way only algorithms. But this was the easiest way I found to explain this.